# import cakePHP SQL tables directly to R

Tags: php, mysql, sql, r, cakephp

We are trying to implement a statistical function on a website which requires a piece of R code, as there are no PHP libraries available and it's not realistic to code it in PHP.

We succeeded in calling the R script from PHP, but now we need the R script to be able to read directly from the SQL tables.

Right now after calling the R script, it uses `read.csv()` to read data from a CSV file that was already exported, but it I would like to be able to read data from the SQL tables in real time.

The workflow we have now:

```
1) Export CSV file from phpmyadmin
2) Call R script from PHP
3) R script reads data from CSV file
4) R script saves data to CSV or tab-delimited file
```

What we need it to be:

```
1) Call R script from PHP
2) R script reads data directly from the SQL tables
3) R script outputs a table that can be interpreted by PHP
```

We're using PHP 5.3 with cakePHP, and R 3.0.2.

Before I get thrown stuff at for not giving a working example, what I really want is not the final code but rather hints on where I should look for a solution, because I tried Google.com, Rseek.org, and a search on stackoverflow, to no avail.

Could it be that I'm missing out on the right keywords? Do you have any tutorials to recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to MySQL and query it directly from R by using [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/). I don't know how do you call the R script from PHP, but using [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.proc-open.php) in detriment of exec will give you a better control, as it uses pipes

Comment: RMySQL did the trick, thanks! Indeed, we are using `exec`. Will keep an eye out for `proc_open` as well in case we ever need the pipes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RServe`. See this code as an example.

https://github.com/nlware/qdnatool/blob/master/app/Model/Exam.php#L539